# No logs when running command from docker container in jenkins

Tags: bash, docker, jenkins

I have a bash script that's running in jenkins which starts a docker container and runs a simple command (PWD), but the output from that command is not written to the build console.  Any ideas what I am misconfiguring?  I've tried various docker arguments but nothing seems to work.  It seems to really be a problem only when executing docker run or docker exec commands.  docker rm commands print output to the jenkins console.

example:

`+ docker run my-image /bin/bash -c pwd`

Note: the jenkins build is also executed in a docker container

Comment: The command above is written in Jenkinsfile or where?

Comment: The command is executed in a jenkins shell script (bash)

Comment: Did you get anything working on this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Jenkins. However, Docker logs are an output of the container's stdio. Since you are seeing docker rm output I presume you are indeed seeing stdout. Sending the output of your script to stdout like: ` 2>&1 | tee /dev/stdout` may be a possible solution? Or something similar maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Using **docker logs -f <container_name_or_id>** might help

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs

*The docker logs --follow command will continue streaming the new output from the container’s STDOUT and STDERR.*